wxGrid does not display scrollbars after assigning custom wxTableBase
I use wxPython. I created a wxGrid widget inside a tab panel. The grid is assigned to a vertial box sizer, which is set as sizer of the panel. When I populate the grid with more rows that can be displayed, a vertical scrollbar is shown and invisible items can be scrolled up/down. Nothing new, works as expected.
Then I assigned a custom table (derived from wxTableBase) to the grid with SetTable():
tabView.SetTable(self.tabData, takeOwnership=True)

Now, the scrollbars do not appear anymore, instead rows are drawn on the available space, cutting of the last row depending on the panel height.
I tried removing AutoSize() and similar function, calling Refresh(), Layout() on the panel but it seems that something in my custom table base is not implemented.
Does anyone know, why the grid assigned with my table base is not displaying scrollbars?

Ok, that is a bit embarrasing but I have found a solution: I dynamically updated the table base. Originally, I called AutoSize() at the end. This prevented the scrollbars from being drawn. If I call AutoSizeColumns() instead then the scrollbars appear and are functional. While I am fine with the solution, I am still not sure what is the cause bt I assume that my table base class was not it.
